# Navigation bar problem - when the browser reaches 768px width, list items get mixed up as seen in the provided snippet

Tags: html, css

This code doesn't work properly when I narrow down the browser. I set a line on 768px. When I narrow the browser about that width, the list items get mixed up. Where is my mistake and why does that happen.

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: auto;
}

nav ul li img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 39px !important;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: azure;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: darkorange;
    color: darkslategrey;
}

.dropdown {
    position: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -1px;
}

.dropdown button {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.dropdown span {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: azure;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    cursor: default;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.dropdown div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    min-width: 10%;
    box-shadow: : 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.dropdown div a {
    color:  white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown div a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

.dropdown:hover div {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover button {
    background-color: darkorange;
}

.dropdown:hover span{
    background-color: darkorange;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul li {
        min-width: 15% !important;
        max-width: 25%;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/70cfac45e9.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li style="min-width: 5%;"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link-4</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <button>dr-menu</button>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">dr-link1</a>
                        <a href="#">dr-link2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">link-5</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <span>dr-menu2</span>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">dr-link1</a>
                        <a href="#">dr-link2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the code above, max width is 768px for list items and my list items mix when when I narrow down the viewport of the browser to or below 768px.

Comment: Hey mate, what do you want to happen with navbar when you narrow the screen?

Comment: List items should continue in next line, but on the 2nd line one of the item float on the right side alone and other items continue on 3rd line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you don't need `@media query`. You can solve it with `flexbox`. Pls look at snippet below :

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: auto;
}

nav ul li img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 39px !important;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: azure;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: darkorange;
    color: darkslategrey;
}

.dropdown {
    position: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
   /* margin: -1px;*/
}

.dropdown button {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.dropdown span {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: azure;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    cursor: default;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.dropdown div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    min-width: 10%;
    box-shadow: : 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.dropdown div a {
    color:  white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown div a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

.dropdown:hover div {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover button {
    background-color: darkorange;
}

.dropdown:hover span{
    background-color: darkorange;
}

/*@media (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul li {
        min-width: 15% !important;
        max-width: 25%;
    }
}*/
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/70cfac45e9.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li style="min-width: 5%;"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link-4</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <button>dr-menu</button>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">dr-link1</a>
                        <a href="#">dr-link2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">link-5</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <span>dr-menu2</span>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">dr-link1</a>
                        <a href="#">dr-link2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```